# Can I override and overload the same function in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to override and overload the same function at the same time in vb.net? 
Something like this:

```
Public Overrides overloads Function Delete(ByVal code As Integer) As Boolean
```

Comment: What happens when you try it? Does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use overloads keyword if your class contains more than one method with same name and different signature. Please see the below code and mark the answer if it's useful

```
Public Class Base

   Public Overridable Function Delete(code As Integer) As Boolean
     Return True
   End Function

End Class

Public Class Derived
Inherits Base

Public Overloads Overrides Function Delete(code As Integer) As Boolean
    Return MyBase.Delete(code)
End Function
Public Overloads Function Delete(code As Integer, id As Integer) As Boolean
    Return MyBase.Delete(code)
End Function

End Class
```

Comment: This does not compile. It shows an error 'Delete cannot be declared 'overrides' because it does not override a function in the base class. And besides, the decorations are swapped here; the second method in the derived class is the one that is overriding the base class method, not the first one.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that, because once you change the signature of the method (which would be the only reason you would want to do this), Overrides will fail to find the underlying method that you want to override.

However, you can have your override or overload call the appropriate internal method or throw an exception if the overridden version is not to be used.

```
Public Overrides Function Delete(ByVal code As Integer) As Boolean
    Throw New Exception("Please use the two parameter version")
End Function

Public Overloads Function Delete(ByVal code As Integer, param2 As Boolean) As Boolean
    MessageBox.Show("This is the right one")
    Return True
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

It might help to think of it this way.  You're asking the function to do 2 different things.

Overload calls basically the same function with a different set of parameters.

Override calls the same function with the same parameters to do something different.